Is it possible to cheaply convert analog to digital at the gigahertz sampling rate?
Consumer software-defined radio devices have become much cheaper and offer sample rates in the tens of million samples per second, but that still seems too low to parse WiFi or ethernet in-software.
Are there any cheap (<$100) devices that turn analog into digital signals with billions of samples per second?  Is there anything that stops this from happening?
It seems modern USB controllers, CPUs and GPUs support a data rate high enough to sample data at the WiFi or ethernet rate and process it in-software, yet this post on Hackaday uses an expensive FPGA setup.

There are inexpensive converters for audio that go up to 192 kHz sample rate.  And video ADC are maybe 10 or 20 MHz, but 1 GHz, is up there in the experimental instrumentation level.  Can't be cheap.

This is tough. I don't know of any GHz range ADCs that are under $100. If you find any, they probably have horrible phase noise or a low bit-count (and poor SNR). Multi-GHz ADCs are widely used in modern systems, but alas they are very very expensive.

None of the things you mention, USB controllers, CPUs nor GPUs, actually do an analog-to-digital conversion as such; yes, things like USB controllers or PCIe devices have equalizers and such; but: the hardware there is very application specific, and digital samples, if any exist in these, never leave the transceiver component. So, I don't think you're doing a fair comparison there.

Also, personal question: Assume you had a 1000 MHz ADC, giving you, say, 8 bit samples. What are you going to attach it to, exactly? What's the first component in the chain after the ADC?

@MarcusMüller Couldn't you just attach it to a USB-C controller?

@Zaz USB-C controllers don't have ADC interfaces; an ADC interface would need to generate the clock for the ADC, it would need some buffering (>8Mbit of dual-port buffer with >8Gbps or single port with >>16Gbps), because USB is a packet bus, and the ADC is producing samples at a constant rate; logic for converting between the ADC clock domain and the USB clock domain(s), and at Gigahertz line rates, your ADC interface will also need relatively advanced signalling tricks like deskewing, equalization/preemphasis and error control. These happen to be expensive components of expensive FPGA series.
